# Would this be a Star Wars ship. What set would it go to? Greys but with dark greens

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Would this be a Star Wars ship.  What set would it go to?

[image: Star Wars, greys but with dark greens]

Answer (score 2):

This is from :

[75168: Yoda's Jedi Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75168-1/Yoda-s-Jedi-Starfighter)
[image]

Keypart

- [Dark Green Wedge, Plate 8 x 3 Left](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=50305&colorID=80&in=A)